# how to get data in views templates

Tags: views, theming

I am trying to use the field data inside of a views template to modify its output. I looked at the available fields with devel, and, inside of a field template, I used the following code:

```
$row->field_field_twitter_screen_name[0]['rendered']['#markup']
```

and many more like this. It worked fine. The only issue is that the page was giving me a lot of notice message from this code:

```
*   Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in include() (line 28 of [path-to-file].tpl.php).
```

Is this not the correct way to get data? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows you the `Notice` because somewhere in your data `array` you have missing data for a specific node. As for being correct, yes, it is a good way to alter the output. Try checking the data before printing it.

Something like

```
if(isset($row->field_field_twitter_screen_name[0]['rendered']['#markup'])) {
  //do custom action here
}
```

Edit: You can also make good use of `$content` variable here.

Comment: what is the content variable, and why don't I see it listed on the template instructions? All I see is $view, $field, $row, $output.

Comment: $content is a variable that contains the content of a page, if you are using a tpl.php, you can access it. Are you using Devel module? if yes try dpm($content); to display the variable structure, if not try 
`echo '<pre>';`
`print_r($content);`
`echo '</pre>';`

Comment: I tried it inside of a field template and it came back blank. Is it available in this template? Why wouldn't be listed as an available variable?